# how does gulp reload work?

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

I have defined a gulpfile.js that looks like this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    connect = require('gulp-connect');

gulp.task('connect', function() {
    console.log('connecting');
    connect.server({
        livereload: true,
        port:35729
    });
});

gulp.task('html', function () {
    console.log('html changed do a reload')
    gulp.src('*.html')
        .pipe(connect.reload());
});

gulp.task('watch', function () {
    console.log('watching');
    gulp.watch(['*.html'], ['html']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['connect', 'watch']);
```

I would like to refresh the page when I change the index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>testing gulpreload</title>
    <link type="text/css" href="css/mystyles.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

When I run the gulp command I can see the following:

```
server started http://localhost:8000
livereload started on port 35729
```

Why is the page not reloaded when I change the index.html? It is showing the 'html changed do a reload' message though.

Comment: When you inspect the dom or network tab in the browser, is there a `livereload.js` file injected / loaded?

Comment: I have the same problem and yes I do see livereload.js in source code....but it's not working

Answer (score 0):

#### In this example you don't need to use connect

#### I have used it like this before:

```
var livereload = require('gulp-livereload');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');

...

gulp.task('watch', function () {
    livereload.listen({port: 35729});

    gulp.watch(['*.html'], ['html']).on('change', livereload.changed);
    gutil.log(gutil.colors.green('Watching for changes...'));
});
```

UPDATE:

As mentioned below in the comments, I forgot to mention that you need to install the [LiveReload](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/livereload/jnihajbhpnppcggbcgedagnkighmdlei?hl=en) Chrome plugin for this to work.

Comment: This is actually not the same. `gulp-livereload` does only send `livereload` events to the specified port and you need either to inject `livereload` or have `livereload` plugin installed in your browser, while `gulp-connect` also servers the page and injects a `livereload` script by itself..

Comment: I updated my question. As for being 'the same', well the end result is what the OP wants to accomplish. This is just another way to do that without using connect.